# LogLogPlot with for negative valued function

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

Is there a way to make a LogLogPlot of a negative-valued function?

I know that with `LogLinearPlot[100 Log[x] Exp[-x], {x, 10^-1, 100},PlotRange -> {-10, 10}]` I can make a plot with a logarithmic scale in the x-axis, but how to do it as well for the y-axis?

Thank you!

Comment: The log of a negative value is complex. What do you want to plot them, the real part, the imaginary part, the modulus... ?

Comment: I'd like to plot just the real part

Comment: Since `Re@Log[x] == Log[Abs@x]` for $x<0$, just plot your function applied to the absolute value of its argument then?

Comment: Well, actually what I'd like is to plot the function just in the region x>0 but with a logarithmic scale in the y-axis. Sorry for not being clear enough...

Comment: `LogLogPlot[100 Log[x] Exp[-x], {x, 10^-1, 100}, 
 PlotRange -> {-10, 10}]`?

Comment: If I try your suggesion I only plot the positive part of the y-axis. The problem is that for x<1 the function becomes negative and mathematica does not continue the plot.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's mathematically unclear and confusing.

Comment: This answer has a LogLogPlot with negatives on both x- and y-axis, ([19542](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/216760/19542)).

Answer (score 3):

A couple of possible work-arounds, which allow you to extend the plot:

```
f[x_] = 100 Log[x] Exp[-x]
LogLogPlot[Abs[f[x]], {x, 10^-1, 100}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
LogLogPlot[{f[x], -f[x]}, {x, 10^-1, 100}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

This second option has the advantage of visually indicating, via color, where the function is positive and where it is negative.

Note that on a logarithmic scale, every unit of distance corresponds to the y-value decreasing by a constant factor.  This means that the point $y = 0$ is infinitely far away on the vertical axis (shades of Zeno's Paradox), and so points with $y \leq 0$ cannot be plotted "to scale" on a logarithmic axis.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Is there a way to map the orange part to negative values (of the y-axis)?

Comment: @Golan:  Not really.  I've added a paragraph at the end to explain why.

Answer (score 1):

```
f[x_] = 100 Log[x] Exp[-x]
```

Simply preferable `PlotRange->Automatic` to `All` in this case. The dip is much deeper than. Another good hack is restricting the `PlotRange`:

```
LogLogPlot[{f[x], -f[x]}, {x, 10^-1, 100}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {10^-6, 200}}]
```

[image: Graphics optimized]

Other values are nice too:

```
LogLogPlot[{f[x], -f[x]}, {x, 10^-1, 50}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {10^-12, 500}}]
```

[image: Graphics optimized]

The further the interval of the plot extends the nicer the asymptotics for large values.

The closer to `1` the interval ends the deeper the dip.

The bigger the lower border of the plot interval the more worse the asymptotic to zero.

The closer to zero the lower border of the plot interval is the better the asymptotic under the price of the loss of the deepness of the dip at `1`.

Nice is therefore:

```
LogLogPlot[{f[x], -f[x]}, {x, 10^-1.5, 50}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {10^-9, 500}}]
```

[image: Graphics optimized]

Mind that the graph is now plotted towards a visual value higher than 100 for x approaching 0. True is that

```
f[0]
```

[image: input and output]

```
Log[f[0]]
```

is positive Infinity.

So the decision to take 0 out of the `Plot` is advisable.

Taking the lower bound to 10^-2 shifts the dip too far to the right.

`1` in the middle of the Plot and the dip as deep as possible are nice criteria.