# How to get negative values of function on Y axis , when i am plotting as LogPlot

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

This might be trivial, but I am not able to get it. I am just keeping it simple.

Suppose I want to plot:

```
Plot[-x, {x, -1, 2}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Next if I want log scale on the Y axis, I am not getting the plot from -2 to 2, which is the range. I want to show those points in the plot, where the function is also negative. I know that `Log[-quantity]` is an imaginary number. Does it mean that when we have a minus value for the function, we can't use `LogPlot`?

```
LogPlot[x, {x, -2, 2}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

How to get the -2 to 0 range of the function, in this case?

Comment: Huh?!?  How do you plot -x and instead show a plot of +x?!?

Answer (score 1):

You can either plot the logarithm of the absolute value:

```
LogPlot[Abs[x], {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or use a [*symmetric logarithmic* scale](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/216760/75628) (symlog):

```
symlog = {
   Function[x, Sign[x]*Log[Abs[x] + 1]], 
   Function[y, Sign[y]*(Exp[Abs[y]] - 1)]};

Plot[x, {x, -200, 200}, ScalingFunctions -> symlog, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, Flatten@Table[{10 ^i, -10 ^i}, {i, 0, 2}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
LogPlot[{x, -x}, {x, -2, 2}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was expecting `ReImPlot` would handle `ScalingFunctions` to give the desired result, but the documentation for `ReImPlot` under Possible Issues says:

```
ScalingFunctions applies to the real and imaginary parts.
```

So perhaps, something like this?

```
ReImPlot[Log[x], {x, -2, 2}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Quiet[
      Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}][#1, #2, {6, 6}]] &, 
    Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Log, Exp}]}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]
```

[image]