# The implementation of "SignedLog" Scaling Function of `Plot`

Tags: plotting, scaling

I recently noticed that the `Plot` function has a new embeded scaling function `SignedLog`, which looks like the matplotlib `symlog`. The implementation of `symlog`-like function is discussed a lot in this forum, such as [symlog-like-plot-with-a-mixed-log-linear-log-scale](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216276/symlog-like-plot-with-a-mixed-log-linear-log-scale), [how-to-get-negative-values-of-function-on-y-axis-when-i-am-plotting-as-logplot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253643/how-to-get-negative-values-of-function-on-y-axis-when-i-am-plotting-as-logplot). Now that Mathematica has its own implementation, I would like to know exactly what function it used.

On a side note, there seems to be some bugs when `Around` and `IntervalMarkers->"Fences"` (or `"Bars"`) are used along with this.

**Edit:**
I figured it out just after I posted this question. So see details in the answer below. Any other thoughts on this topic is welcomed.

Comment: Oh heck yeah.  Thanks for finding this!

Answer (score 6):

My guess is it's not `symlog` described in [the first post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216276/symlog-like-plot-with-a-mixed-log-linear-log-scale):

```
symlog = {Function[x, Sign[x] (Log[Abs[x] + 1])], 
  Function[y, Sign[y] (Exp[Abs[y]] - 1)]};
```

I tested it with the following example:

```
Show[Plot[x, {x, -10, 10}, ScalingFunctions -> "SignedLog", 
 PlotLabels -> "SignedLog"], 
 Plot[x, {x, -10, 10}, ScalingFunctions -> symlog, 
 PlotStyle -> Orange, PlotLabels -> "symlog"], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Although it looks like

```
symlog10 = {Function[x, Sign[x] (Log10[Abs[x] + 1])], 
  Function[y, Sign[y] (10^Abs[y] - 1)]};
```

[image]

The manual also indicated another use (`ScalingFunctions -> {"SignedLog", a}`):

```
Show[Plot[x, {x, -10, 10}, ScalingFunctions -> {"SignedLog", 1/100}, 
  PlotLabels -> "{SignedLog,1/100}"], 
 Plot[x, {x, -10, 10}, ScalingFunctions -> symlog10, 
  PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Orange}, PlotLabels -> "symlog10"], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Seems like the scaled `symlog` works:

```
symlog10a[a_] := {Function[x, Sign[x] (Log10[Abs[x]/a + 1])], 
  Function[y, Sign[y] (10^Abs[y] - 1) a]};

Show[Plot[x, {x, -10, 10}, ScalingFunctions -> {"SignedLog",                 
  1/100}, 
    PlotLabels -> "{SignedLog,1/100}"], 
   Plot[x, {x, -10, 10}, ScalingFunctions -> "SignedLog", 
      PlotLabels -> "{SignedLog}"], 
     Plot[x, {x, -10, 10}, ScalingFunctions -> symlog10a[1/100], 
      PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Orange}, PlotLabels -> "symlog10"], 
     PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**EDIT:**
Looks like there is a `Floor` function in `SignedLog`. The corresponding `symlog10` should be:

```
symlog10aFloor[a_] := With[{aa=10^Floor@Log10@a},{Function[x, Sign[x] 
  (Log10[Abs[x]/aa + 1])], 
  Function[y, Sign[y] (10^Abs[y] - 1) aa]}];

Show[Plot[x, {x, -10, 10}, ScalingFunctions -> {"SignedLog",     7/100}, 
  PlotLabels -> "{SignedLog,7/100}"], 
 Plot[x, {x, -10, 10}, ScalingFunctions -> "SignedLog", 
  PlotLabels -> "{SignedLog}"], 
 Plot[x, {x, -10, 10}, ScalingFunctions -> symlog10aFloor[7/100], 
  PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Orange}, PlotLabels -> "symlog10Floor"], 
 Plot[x, {x, -10, 10}, ScalingFunctions -> symlog10a[5/100], 
  PlotStyle -> {Red}, PlotLabels -> "symlog10_old"], PlotRange -> All]
```

such that

[image]