# Log Scale in region plot

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

How to make both x- and y-axes in log scale for the `RegionPlot` written below?

```
RegionPlot[-0.02 < z < 0.0002, {x, -0.00005, 1}, {y, -0.00005, 5}]
```

Answer (score 6):

First, note that the predicate (i.e. the first argument) in your [`RegionPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html) does not actually depend on the variables you're trying to plot over.

To answer your question about log-axes however, you can use [`ScalingFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html). To demonstrate, I'll use a predicate example from the documentation:

(**Edit 01:** Using "SignedLog" instead based on @Bob Hanlon's comment below)

```
RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"SignedLog", "SignedLog"}]
```

[image]

**Edit 02:** "SignedLog" appears to have been introduced to `ScalingFunctions` recently. You can however define custom `ScalingFunctions`, e.g. from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/216760):

```
symlog = {
  Function[x, Sign[x] * Log[Abs[x] + 1]], 
  Function[y, Sign[y] * (Exp[Abs[y]] - 1)]};
}

RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {symlog, symlog}
```

Comment: Or since your variables can be negative, "SignedLog", e.g., `RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"SignedLog", "SignedLog"}]`

Comment: Thanks, @BobHanlon for your answer. However, when I try to implement your suggestion in Mathematica, it is not working. "ScalingFunctions -> {"SignedLog", "SignedLog"}" --- this part is coming out in red color and error is "The function value {SignedLog[{1.}]} is not a list of real numbers \
with dimensions {1} when the arguments are {{1}}".

Comment: @SahabubJahedi - `ScalingFunctions` was updated in 2021 (v13.0)

Comment: @BobHanlon, I see. I am using v12.0. Is there any different way to do this in v12.0?

Comment: @SahabubJahedi - not that I'm aware of.

Comment: @SahabubJahedi: I believe [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/216760) answers your question for pre v13.0 "SignedLog" functionality. See updated answer

Comment: @GeorgeVarnavides, thanks for the link and update. But I still could not get the expected plot. It seems that ScalingFunctions is not working in RegionPlot. It again turned out to be red.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you've tried please? Did you change the predicate to something depending on the variables you're plotting over?

Comment: @BobHanlon, Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated Mathematica to version 13 and it is working fine.

Comment: @GeorgeVarnavides, Thanks for your concern. This suggestion is working fine in Mathematica 13.